# how to make a path with read write access in zend form captcha

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha

I have added captcha in Zend form. In this captcha image is generated automatically and saved in captcha folder.

When accessed in server (AWS), in html page that captcha image is not loading because, the path is not readable and writable.

Here is the code I have used for creating the zend form with captcha:

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
                                                            'captcha' => array(
                                                                'captcha' => 'Image',
                                                                'wordLen' => 5,
                                                                'timeout' => 300,
                                                                'expiration' => 300,
                                                                'font' => './fonts/calibri_bold.ttf',
                                                                'imgDir' => './captcha/',
                                                                'imgUrl' => '/captcha/'
                                                            )
                                            ));   

        $captcha->removeDecorator('ViewHelper');
```

How to make the `imgDir` path with read & write access?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue fixed by finding the captcha image path in php and provided access to read the image file. Below is the code:

```
public function giveCaptchaFolderAccess() {
    $Path = realpath("../public/captcha");
    $dp = opendir($Path);
    while ($File = readdir($dp)) {
        if ($File != "." AND $File != "..") {
            if (is_dir($File)) {
                chmod($File, 0744);
                chmod_r($Path . "/" . $File);
            } else {
                chmod($Path . "/" . $File, 0744);
            }
        }
    } closedir($dp);
}
```